# Read-in CustomerID from Sheet1, find CustomerID on Sheet 2, copy/paste CustomerName to Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new at excel, so please bear with me.

On Sheet1 of my workbook I have data like CostumerID, CostumerName, Email and so on spread in columns A-G. CostumerID is filled with ID's and CostumerName is empty.

On Sheet2 of my workbook I have 2 columns (A and B). Column A contains CustomerID and column B contains the correct CustomerName for that CustomerID.

My problem is:

I need a macro that goes to Sheet1, reads the CustomerID in column A, then goes to Sheet2, find that CustomerID also in column A, get the CustomerName in column B and paste that name to column B in Sheet1 next to cell from which it got the first CustomerID.

Further ellaboration:

Step 1: Get value of cell in column A on Sheet 1

Step 2: Go to Sheet2, find that value in column A, then copy CustomerName from same row.

Step 3: Paste that CostumerName into column B on the same row as original value from column A on Sheet1.

Sheet1 can be 100-6000 rows, and it needs to check all CustomerID's in column A in Sheet1 and find the corresponding CustomerName. There can be duplicates in column A on Sheet1, but the value of columns D, F and G are all unique.

Normally I would present my attempt on how to do this, but I have no idea how to do this.

Anybody have an idea?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to use VBA: use VLOOKUP to achieve this - see https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65 to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**" Mark Wickett "** has correctly pointed it out.
But if you still want to go to the vba than here it is.

say here is the screenshot of your first sheet
[image]

and here is screenshot of your second sheet

[image]

Here is the Code

```
Dim rngCust As Range
Dim rNo As Long
Dim strCust As String
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim intFound As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngCust = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In rngCust.Cells
        rNo = cell.Row
        strCust = Cells(rNo, 1).Value
        Sheets(2).Select
            Set rngSearch = Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=strCust, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                intFound = rngFound.Row
            End If
        Sheets(1).Select
        Sheets(1).Cells(rNo, 2).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(intFound, 2).Value

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**here is the Output**

[image]